# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, but print_r command display value

Tags: warnings

My code gave this warning, but when i print_r the row, it display the value selected.
So how do i solve this

This is the code "
    $query3 = ("Select b.*, c.ScrubNurseName from scrubnurse b, surgery a, scrubnurselist c
           where b.rn_no = '$id'
           and a.SurgId = b.SurgId
           and b.ScrubNurse = c.ScrubNurseID
           ORDER BY b.SurgId, b.SerialNo");

```
               $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
               $row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);

               <?php
        /*try utk display scrubnurse */
        print_r($row3);
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){?>
            <p>Scrub Nurse : <?php echo $row3['ScrubNurse'];?>
            <p>Status : <?php echo $row3['Status'];?>
        <?php }
```

and this is the result from print_r($row3)
             Scrub Nurse Array ( [0] => 16 
             [SerialNo] => 16 [1] =>
             rand52fad80207b6a1.33040579 [SurgID] => rand52fad80207b6a1.33040579 [2] 
             => RN001-13 [Rn_No] => RN001-13 [3] =>
             2014-02-10 [Surg_Date] => 2014-02-10 [4] => 015405 [ScrubNurse] => 
             015405 [5] => C [SNRole] => C [6] => Azhari Landut [ScrubNurseName] => Azhari 
             Landut )

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cotds3\editpt_surgery2.php on line 470

Answer (score 0):

In line while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){? there is typo it should be while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){?